# Query giving different Values

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I am stripping off a few unwanted fields and putting in one qualifier in the where clause.
When exported to excel, and all of the fields in Load Size (see first query) are removed, i get 84 rows.
In the second query, i simply remove a few fields and add the qualifier to get rid of those fields which have a load size of 0. i run it with the same parameters, but get 87 rows. I have no clue as to what removal has triggered this.
Original Query:

```
    Declare @start Varchar(20),
            @end VarChar(20),
            @division varchar(2),
            @group varchar(20)

            set @start = '02/01/2015'
            set @end = '02/09/2015'
            set @division= '02'
            set @group  = 'anodize'

    --Get the most recent order date
SELECT
    MAX(DATEPHYSICAL) AS 'DATEPHYSICAL',
    ITEMID
INTO
    #tempOrderDates
FROM
    dbo.INVENTTRANS
GROUP BY
    ITEMID

SELECT 
    ITEMID,
    SUM(dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.QTY) AS 'Quanity',
    SUM(LINEAMOUNTMST) AS 'Sales',
    COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.SALESID) AS 'Total Orders'
INTO
    #tempItemRevenue
FROM
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS ON dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID = dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEID
WHERE
    dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.DIMENSION2_ IN (@division)
    AND
    CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE, 101) BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY
    ITEMID

SELECT
    ITEMGROUPID AS 'Process',
    [DESCRIPTION] AS 'Division',
    dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID AS 'Item ID',
    EXTITEM AS 'Cust Item ID',
    dbo.INVENTTABLE.CUSTNAME AS 'Customer',
    cu.[SalesGroup],
    dbo.USERINFO.NAME AS 'Sales Engineer',
    cu.[Street],
    cu.[City],
    cu.[State],
    cu.[ZipCode],
    ISNULL(PRICE / CASE WHEN PRICEUNIT = 0 THEN NULL ELSE PRICEUNIT END, 0) AS 'Unit Price',
    PRICEDATE AS 'Date of Price',
    LOADQTY AS 'Load Size',
    LOADQTY * ISNULL(PRICE / CASE WHEN PRICEUNIT = 0 THEN NULL ELSE PRICEUNIT END, 0) AS 'Load Value',
    Sales,
    Quanity,
    [Total Orders],
    CEILING(ISNULL(Quanity / CASE WHEN [Total Orders] = 0 THEN NULL ELSE [Total Orders] END, 0)) AS 'Avg. Order Quanity',
    DATEPHYSICAL AS 'Last Order Date'
FROM
    dbo.INVENTTABLE INNER JOIN 
    dbo.INVENTTABLEMODULE ON dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID = dbo.INVENTTABLEMODULE.ITEMID INNER JOIN 
    #tempOrderDates ON dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID = #tempOrderDates.ITEMID INNER JOIN 
    #tempItemRevenue ON dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID = #tempItemRevenue.ITEMID INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DIMENSIONS ON NUM = dbo.INVENTTABLE.DIMENSION2_ INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CUSTTABLE cu ON ACCOUNTNUM = CUSTACCOUNT LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.SMMSALESUNITMEMBERS ON SALESUNITID = cu.SALESGROUP AND SALESMANAGER = 1 INNER JOIN 
    dbo.USERINFO ON ID = SALESMANID
WHERE
    MODULETYPE = 2
    AND
    ITEMGROUPID IN (@group)
    AND
    dbo.INVENTTABLE.DIMENSION2_ IN (@division)

DROP TABLE #tempOrderDates
DROP TABLE #tempItemRevenue
```

Modified query getting rid of salesman stuff and customer information:

```
    Declare @start Varchar(20),
        @end VarChar(20),
        @division varchar(2),
        @group varchar(20)

        set @start = '02/01/2015'
        set @end = '02/09/2015'
        set @division= '02'
        set @group  = 'anodize'



SELECT 
    ITEMID,
    SUM(dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.QTY) AS 'Quanity',
    SUM(LINEAMOUNTMST) AS 'Sales',
    COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.SALESID) AS 'Total Orders'
INTO
    #tempItemRevenue
FROM
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS ON dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID = dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEID
WHERE
    dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.DIMENSION2_ IN (@division)
    AND
    CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEDATE, 101) BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY
    ITEMID

SELECT
    ITEMGROUPID AS 'Process',
    [DESCRIPTION] AS 'Division',
    LOADQTY AS 'Load Size',
    LOADQTY * ISNULL(PRICE / CASE WHEN PRICEUNIT = 0 THEN NULL ELSE PRICEUNIT END, 0) AS 'Load Value',
    Sales,
    Quanity

FROM
    dbo.INVENTTABLE 
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo.INVENTTABLEMODULE ON dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID = dbo.INVENTTABLEMODULE.ITEMID 
    inner JOIN 
    #tempItemRevenue ON dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID = #tempItemRevenue.ITEMID 
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DIMENSIONS ON NUM = dbo.INVENTTABLE.DIMENSION2_ 


WHERE
    MODULETYPE = 2
    AND
    ITEMGROUPID IN (@group)
    AND
    dbo.INVENTTABLE.DIMENSION2_ IN (@division)
    and LOADQTY >0


DROP TABLE #tempItemRevenue
```

I don;t understand what is missing that gives me different results. I have tried picking the query apart bit by bit but i do not see where it breaks.

Comment: Your query looks like you are expecting to have multiple value in your group and division variables. You can't do that with variable the way you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely in the joins you removed. If you remove the salesman and customer tables, you're likely to be bringing back rows that those joins were removing.

I'd suggest checking the values in the joins to see what the difference is. You may have some NULLs or some ID's that aren't present or rows where this isn't true: `SALESMANAGER = 1`.

Seeing at there are only 84 and 87 rows respectively, you should be able to check the difference by eye, then inspect those records for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you removed some INNER JOIN also: this probably causes more rows to come up. Try to remove just fields and leave INNER JOINS as for the first query.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First query you were joining the table `CUSTTABLE` and in the second query not.

It is possible you find 3 extra rows that have no connection to the `CUSTTABLLE` table

Answer (score 0):

My first choice for the difference would be in the removal of #tempOrderDates or CustTable. They were in Inner joins, so the removal coud make other records available that were not in the orginal query.

Since your result set is so small, look for an example of a record that is in the second result set and not the first one. Then,take the original query, change to a select * and change all the inner joins you removed in the second query to left joins  and see what the table data looks like that brought thsoe records in. You might consider filtering on just the record(s) you are interested in seeing.